# Spurious space? depending on keepaspectratio

Tags: spacing, mdframed, includegraphics

Please check the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle1}{
  apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={},}},
  extra={
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node
        [xshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxwidth, yshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxheight, opacity=.4]
        {\includegraphics
          [width=\mdfboundingboxwidth, height=\mdfboundingboxheight]
          {example-image}
        };
    }
  }
}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle2}{
  apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={},}},
  extra={
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node
        [xshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxwidth, yshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxheight, opacity=.4]
        {\includegraphics
          [width=\mdfboundingboxwidth, height=\mdfboundingboxheight, keepaspectratio]
          {example-image}
        };
    }
  }
}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle3}{
  apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={},}},
  extra={
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node
        [xshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxwidth, yshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxheight, opacity=.4]
        {\includegraphics
          [width=\mdfboundingboxwidth, height=\mdfboundingboxheight, keepaspectratio=true]
          {example-image}
        };
    }
  }
}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle4}{
  apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={},}},
  extra={
    \scoped[on background layer]{
      \node
        [xshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxwidth, yshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxheight, opacity=.4]
        {\includegraphics
          [width=\mdfboundingboxwidth, height=\mdfboundingboxheight, keepaspectratio=false]
          {example-image}
        };
    }
  }
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle1]
    mystyle1
    \blindtext
  \end{mdframed}
  \begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle2]
    mystyle2
    \blindtext
  \end{mdframed}
  \begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle3]
    mystyle3
    \blindtext
  \end{mdframed}
  \begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle4]
    mystyle4
    \blindtext
  \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Here is the corresponding output:
[image]

Where does the spacing issue for `mystyle1` and `mystyle4` come from (frames are misplaced from the body)? Is it maybe a bug?

Regards, Ivan

Comment: we can not run your example as LaTeX.pdf is not available, can you demonstrate using `example-image` or some other available test image? Also can you state more clearly what spacing issue you see

Comment: in one and 4 the image is `\mdfboundingboxwidth` wide so presumably you are falling foul of the node inner sep or some other padding space making the combination too wide.

Comment: I edited the original post. It seems like you already figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You need to set the inner sep to zero to leave room for a full width image, as done in case 4 here.

```
    [inner sep = 0pt,xshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxwidth, yshift=.5*\mdfboundingboxheight, opacity=.4]
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```